# Ways of arranging $n$ boys (and $m-n$ girls) in $m$ seats such that at least one boy is alone

Tags: combinatorics

Given $m$ seats, as well as $n$ (non-distinct) boys and $m-n$ (non-distinct) girls, find the number of arrangements such that at least one boy sits alone (no adjacent boys).

This is somewhat similar to the problem where everyone in a particular group as to be separated when seated, which was what I thought of (giving the answer $\binom{m-n+1}{n}$ in this case), but since we're looking for arrangements with at least one lone boy, I don't know where to start.

Comment: There is always one lone boy. :(